# Whose symbol is on this Marvel belt?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

I was gifted this magnificent belt that features the logo of several Marvel characters, specifically members of the Avengers. From top to bottom: Nick Fury/S.H.I.E.L.D., Hulk, Iron Man, Thor, **unknown**, Captain America, Hawkeye, and Black Widow. My question is: what character is represented by the image between Thor and Captain America? I think that it could be Scarlet Witch or Falcon, my brother thinks that it's Ant-Man. Who is it?

[image]

Comment: It's the falcon. I searched for 'avengers symbol' that lead to this link: https://www.reddit.com/r/future_fight/comments/5vaif2/request_name_these_alliance_emblem_logos/  I then searched "falcon symbol" and got back that same icon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based upon the results of a few Google searches, that symbol appears to be one of several used for Falcon.  See ["New Disney Cast Member Pin"](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/disney-cast-member-exclusive-marvel-1814898558) (the same pin also is offered at [a pin trading database](https://www.pintradingdb.com/pin/7958)); also see (less authoritatively) [the MCU Wiki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/f/p/3300297438920721201) and, oddly, animal information site [Animalia Life](http://animalia-life.club/other/marvel-falcon-symbol.html).

Here's a screenshot of the first linked webpage, in case it ceases to exist.

[image]

Comment: Your first link has no image attached

Comment: I get an image following the link?

Comment: @Michael - I think it's behind a paywall. You'd be better posting images than weblinks anyway, in case they die

Comment: Not my post, and don't know enough about it to edit. I don't have any subscription to the site and get an image when I follow the link.

Comment: @Valorum: while worthpoint (the domain for the link) does seem to offer a subscription service, I certainly haven’t paid them anything and I see an image and it includes the text “What's My Name Badge FALCON Pin” which does seem to indicate this for the Falcon.

Comment: @jmoreno - I think it might be a regional block. When I use my VPN to view it from the States, it works fine. When I use it elsewhere, it's either blocked or comes up as a dead link. Either way it would be better to post the picture here as the answer will become worthless if the links die

Comment: Here’s a different link, not sure of the source, it’s not exactly the same as in the source image (different colors and it includes the word falcon around the rim) https://images.thesouledstore.com/public/theSoul/uploads/catalog/product/20160526133451-1.jpg

Comment: FWIW, I'm in the UK like Valorum, and it works fine for me. Perhaps a temporary connectivity/routing problem on your ISP's part.

Comment: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Falcon-Marvel-Comics-Mens-T-Shirt-Distressed-Logo-of-Captain-America-s-Buddy/579181199

Comment: Sorry, everyone, about the faulty link. It worked fine for me (still does) and being a relative noob it didn't occur to me to take the time to figure out how to post an image of the symbol along with the link. Having followed dead links from this site in the past I know it's a potential problem. I'll try to figure it out.